# Importing SQL Server 2008 stored procedure into Excel 2016 I get an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am importing a stored procedure from SQL Server 2008 into Excel 2016, and get an error when I execute it in Excel:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to date

This is the stored procedure `[LA_VOTER].[Temp].[dmv_import]`:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:           Arash B
-- Create date: 6/5/2018
-- Description:      test for creating dynamic 'Data Entry Signature Verification' worksheeet
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [Temp].[dmv_import]
    @date DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @date_work DATE

    IF @date IS NULL
       SET @date_work = GETDATE()
    ELSE
       SET @date_work = @date 

    /*count of processed*/
    SELECT 
        vi.import_code as 'DMV Category',
        SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(date, vi.createdate, 101) = @date_work THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'received',
        SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(date, vi.processed_date, 101) = @date_work THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'processed'
    FROM 
        DIMSNet.dbo.voter_import vi
    WHERE 
        vi.import_type IN ('DMV')
        AND import_code < 13
    GROUP BY 
        import_code
END
```

I access it in Excel through  Data – From Other Sources shown below.

I select from SQL and enter “slavote-dr1” for server to connect to; “DIMSNet” the selected table and any random table as instructions indicated.

Once I reach the “Import Data” pop-up window I select the Cell in the excel worksheet I want to drop the table onto and click on the “properties” button.

Chose the “Definition” tab and changed command type to “SQL”.

Entered the executable in the “Command Text box”. Since the database use to connect I inserted the full path for the stored procedure on the command line.

```
Execute "LA_VOTER"."Temp"."dmv_import" ","
```

I click “OK” and return to the “Import Data” window.  I click “Ok” to import the table.

I get the error stated above.

I looked at the script and could not see where this error was coming from. Is there anything that you can suggest?

PS. Added 6/12/18  ----- The SP runs fine in SQL.  It is only when importing into Excel that the issue occurs.

Comment: Why are you passing in a comma when the parameter for the stored procedure is a date?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean It returns the columns empty into the Excel worksheet.  We can enter the parameter in later and refresh the page to populate based on the parameter entered using AcitvX Command Buttion and Vbasic to pass teh parameter to the script.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3436/passing-dynamic-query-values-from-excel-to-sql-server/

Comment: Your code quoted in the question is using quotes ("), not double apostrophes (''). Is that literally what the code is, or was that an error in posting the question?

Comment: That was a typing mistake on my part it is double apostrophes ('')

Answer (score 0):

The failure is undoubtedly in the stored procedure.  It is almost certainly in these lines:

```
sum(case when convert(date, vi.createdate, 101) = @date_work then 1 else 0 end) as received,
sum(case when convert(date, vi.processed_date, 101) = @date_work then 1 else 0 end) as processed
```

I would suggest that you find the problems in the data and fix them.  You can possibly fix the problem by doing:

```
sum(case when isdate(vi.createdate) = 0 then 0
         when convert(date, vi.createdate, 101) = @date_work then 1 
         else 0
    end) as received,
sum(case when isdate(vi.processed_date) = 0 then 0
         when convert(date, vi.processed_date, 101) = @date_work
         then 1
         else 0
    end) as processed
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff for the suggestion.
I replaced my code with yours and still got the same error.

Comment: @user9909962 . . . Do you still get an error if you comment out those two lines?

Comment: I Commented out the 2 lines and still get the same error as before:

SELECT vi.import_code as 'DMV Category' 
--,sum(case when convert(date,vi.createdate,110) = *@*date_work then 1 else 0 end) as 'received'
--,sum(case when convert(date,vi.processed_date,110) = *@*date_work then 1 else 0 end) as 'processed'
FROM DIMSNet.dbo.voter_import vi
WHERE 
vi.import_type in ('DMV')
and import_code < 13 

group by import_code

END

Answer (score 0):

OK used a different method and got it working.
Used the "From Microsoft Query" and my Execute script was:
**{CALL LA_VOTE.tmp.dmv_import(?)}** and it imported the data I needed into the fields I wanted.

http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-data-from-sql-server-stored.html